# Cancan, issue with checking class abilities

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cancan

I have this code:

```
can :create, Project { |instance| some_statement }
```

Later I want to add such condition: if user can create some `Project`, then he can read `ProjectTemplate`. But I can't do this like this:

```
if can? :create, Project
  can :read, ProjectTemplate
end
```

Because if-condition always true. Also, I can't just put can? `:create`, Project.new, because in my can `:create, Project {}` statement is not just `.new object`.

Any suggestions? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

To look at it a slightly different way, can you not have a role whereby the user is able to create projects (e.g. project_creator) and then just use the following

```
    if user.role? :project_creator
      can :create, Project { |instance| some_statement }
      can :read, ProjectTemplate
    end
```

I realize this isn't exactly what you want, but I am assuming it's not so much of a security risk for a wise group of people to read templates?

I'm also a bit confused that you have a condition on creating projects, the instance statement means that some logic is being applied on a specific instance. However, if a project has not been created there is no instance?

The way I have used that method is similar to the following

```
can [:read], User do |thisuser|
  thisuser == user
end
```